# Bokeh circle plot color in ColumnDataSource

Tags: python, plot, colors, bokeh

I am trying to display my clusters in an interactive circle plot with Bokeh. I managed to display the plot itself, but all the specs on the graph are blue. I want to display them in 4 clusters, since this is a cluster analyses.

This is the code that works without the implementation of color:

```
colormap = {0: 'brown', 1: 'green', 2: 'blue', 3: 'purple'}
colors = [colormap[x] for x in df['cluster']]

source = ColumnDataSource(data=df)
hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[('index', '@index'),('Tweets','@Bericht'), ('Polarity','@Polarity'), ('Subjectivity','@Subjectivity')])

p = figure(title = "Sentiment analyse", plot_width=1000, plot_height=500)
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Polarity'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Subjectivity'

p.circle(x='Polarity', y='Subjectivity', source=source, fill_alpha=0.2, size=6)

p.add_tools(hover)



output_file("sentiment.html", title="sentiment.py example")

show(p)
```

When adding the color attribute `color=colors` in `p.circle`, I get an error because I need to implement the color in the `source = ColumnDataSource(data=df)`.

Does anyone know how to implement this `colors` attribute in the `ColumnDataSource`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a dict of values:colors, and then create a new column in your dataframe. Here is a simplified example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"col1":[0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]})
colors =  {0: "brown", 1: "green", 2: "blue", 3: "purple"}
df["color"] = df["col1"].apply(lambda c: colors[c])
```

Comment: Thank you, you gave me inspiration! I changed my code a bit. Solution: `df['colors'] = [colormap[x] for x in df['cluster']]`

Comment: That's a nice solution!

Comment: Instead of the `apply` you can also use `df['col1'].map(colors)`.